# How to remove all " \n" in xml payload by using lxml library

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to change a text value in xml file, and I need to return the updated xml content by using lxml library. I can able to successfully update the value, but the updated xml file contains "\n"(next line) character as below.

***Output:***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>\n<Order>\n   <content>\n <sID>123</sID>\n   <spNumber>UserTemp</spNumber>\n  <client>ARRCHANA</client>\n <orderType>Dashboard</orderType>\n </content>\n
<content>\n <sID>111</sID>\n   <spNumber>UserTemp</spNumber>\n  <client>ARRCHANA</client>\n <orderType>Dashboard</orderType>\n </content>\n
</Order>
```

Note: I didn't format the above xml output, and posted it how exactly I get it from output console.

***Input:***

```
  <Order>
    <content>
      <sID>123</sID>
       <spNumber>UserTemp</spNumber>
       <client>WALLMART</client>
       <orderType>Dashboard</orderType>
    </content>
    <content>
       <sID>111</sID>
       <spNumber>UserTemp</spNumber>
       <client>D&B</client>
       <orderType>Dashboard</orderType>
     </content>
   </Order>
```

Also, I tried to remove the \n character in output xml file by using

```
getValue = getValue.replace('\n','')
```

but, no luck.

The below code I used to update the xml( tag), and tried to return the updated xml content back.

**Python Code:**

```
    from lxml import etree
    from io import StringIO
    import six
    import numpy

    def getListOfNodes(location):
        f = open(location)
        xml = f.read()
        f.close()
        #print(xml)
        getXml = etree.parse(location)
        for elm in getXml.xpath('.//Order//content/client'):
            index='ARRCHANA'
            elm.text=index
        #with open('C:\\New folder\\temp.xml','w',newline='\r\n') as writeFile:
        
        #writeFile.write(str(etree.tostring(getXml,pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)))
        getValue=str((etree.tostring(getXml,pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)))
        #getValue = getValue.replace('\n','') 
        #getValue=getValue.replace("\n","<br/>")
        print(getValue)
        return getValue
```

When I'm trying to open the response payload through firefox browser, then It says the below error message:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>
> file:///C:/New%20folder/Confidential.xml
> Line Number 1, Column 1:

It says that "no element found location in Line Number 1, column 1" in xml file when it found "\n" character in it.

Can somebody assist me the better way to update the text value, and return it back without any additional characters.

Comment: What's wrong with the new line characters?  Are they causing a problem?  Also are you sure the new lines aren't being added by `pretty_print=True`?

Comment: Just checking: when you do `replace`, you're assigning the result to something, right? Like, you're doing `s = s.replace('\n','')` and not just `s.replace('\n','') ` by itself?

Comment: The newline characters don't matter as long as they're not between begin and end tags.

Comment: You say `pretty_print=True` and that adds newlines and spaces.

Comment: I'm confused. Does the input XML have pretty printing (extra spaces and newlines) and you want all pretty printing removed when you are done? Your sample XML doesn't match your code: "sample request xml" isn't valid, "sample response" doesn't have the ARRCHANA in it. It would be better to post a working example so we can take your input without modification and tweak your script for the output you want.

Comment: @RolandSmith - everything is between begin and end tags. Unless otherwise controlled by a DTD or Schema, newlines and spaces are included in the document text nodes. If you accept pretty-printed xml, you may need to normalize text nodes (e.g., `elm.text = elm.text.strip()`). And if you allow embedded tags like `<div>Text with <i>italics</i> and <b>bold</b> have multiple text nodes</div>` then you have multiple text nodes you need to consider and can't use `elem.text` to get the full text of nodes.

Comment: The request payload has huge element, that's the reason I didn't paste the whole xml file. I update my question with proper example.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat Actually the "\n" character is not let me to parse the response xml file.  Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: The updated question does not contain code that we can run. What is `location`?. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @arrchanaMohan: Have you tried removing `pretty_print=True`?

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat  I tried that too but no luck. please find my test script , and commented it.

Comment: The input contains a unescaped `&` character. And `<sID111</sID>` should be `<sID>111</sID>`. So that cannot be the real input document.

Comment: @Mazjn  The input xml is very complex one(Huge elements), and It's not possible to post the whole content since it contains confidential things. I'm just looking some idea how to update the given sample xml file by the way I can apply my logic to fix my real scenario. I'm not interested to assign my homework to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by myself by using the below script:

```
code = root.xpath('.//Order//content/client')
if code:
    code[0].text = 'ARRCHANA'
    etree.ElementTree(root).write('D:\test.xml', pretty_print=True)
```